# If $X|Y$ is a delta distribution, is $Y|X$ also a delta distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X,Y$ be two continuous random variables with density functions $f_X,f_Y$. Suppose $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\delta(x-F(y))$, where $F$ is some function of $y$. Does this mean that $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \delta(y-G(x))$ where $G$ is some function of $x$?

I tried to approach this using Bayes' theorem

$$
f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X|Y}(x|y)f_Y(y)}{f_X(x)} = \frac{\delta(x-F(y))f_Y(y)}{f_X(x)} = \frac{\delta(x-F(y))f_Y(y)}{f_X(F(y))}
$$
where I use the property of $\delta$ such that $\delta(x-x_0)f(x) = f(x_0)\delta(x-x_0)$. I am not so sure how to continue from here. I am also not able to think of a counterexample.

Comment: if x=y^2 then x|y is a delta but y|x is a sum of deltas

Comment: $F(y)$ being a piecewise step function is another counterexample in which your property does not hold. Suppose for instance $x = 7$ if $y > 0$ and $x = 5$ otherwise, $f_{Y|X}(y|  x=7)$ can be continuous and with various shapes.